# Не открывает модальное окно при нажатии на кнопку (electron js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Делаю предложение на electron по tutorial -у [если кому интересно будет](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RxHQoiDctI)

Добрался до создания модального окна при нажатии на кнопку и не как не получается это сделать.

main.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = require('electron')
const shell = require('electron').shell

function createWindow() {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    })
    
    win.loadFile('src/index.html').then(r => win)

    win.webContents.openDevTools()

    var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
        {
            label: 'Menu',
            submenu: [
                {label: 'Adjust Notification Value'},
                {
                    label: 'Coin Market Cap',
                    click() {
                        shell.openExternal('https://coinmarketcap.com')
                    }
                },
                {type: "separator"},
                {
                    label: 'Exit',
                    click() {
                        app.quit()
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'Info'
        }
    ])

    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {    
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow()
    }
})

process.env['ELECTRON_DISABLE_SECURITY_WARNINGS'] = 'true';
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cripto</title>
    <!-- https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#csp-meta-tag -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="price-container">
            <p class="subtext">Current BTC USD</p>
            <h1 id="price">Loading...</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="goal-container">
            <p><img src="../assets/images/up.svg" alt=""><span id="targetPrice">Choose a Target Price</span></p>
        </div>
        <div id="right-container">
            <button id="notifyBtn">Notify me when...</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

add.js

```
const electron = require('electron').remote
const path = require('path')

const {BrowserWindow} = electron.BrowserWindow

const notifyBtn = document.getElementById('notifyBtn')

notifyBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const modalPath = path.join('file://', __dirname, 'add.js')
    let win = new BrowserWindow({ frame: false })

    win.on('close', () => { win = null })
    win.loadURL(modalPath)
    win.show()
})
```

add.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#csp-meta-tag -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/add.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p class="notify">Notify me when BTC reaches...</p>

    <div class="row2">
        <div>
            <input id="notifyVal" placeholder="USD">
        </div>
        <button id="updateBtn">Update</button>
    </div>

    <a id="closeBtn">Close window</a>

    <script src="add.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

На electronjs пишу первый раз, не как не пойму в чём проблема. При дебаге, при нажатии на кнопку, до  add.js, дебаг не доходит. Такое чувство, что он эту страницу просто не видит. Возможно, в новых версиях где то зарезолвить что то нужно?